# Spring MongoRepository, where to catch the exception?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-mongodb

I have a Spring project, and a MongoRepository. The MongoRepository is an Interface that extends MongoRepository, just like JPA.

If I try to build my project with `mvn clean install` it runs Spring once. Spring tries to connect to MongoDB which is not running on my Jenkins server.

> exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}

Is there a way to catch the exception? I cannot catch it on the service where I call my repository, because those methods are not executed. I think it has something to do with `@autowire`, but I can't figure out how to catch the exception.

The architecture:

```
application
  - resource (api)
  - service
  - repository extends MongoRepository
```

The application scans the project, the resource calls the service, the service calls the repository and the repository throws an error because it cannot connect to MongoDB.

**Repository:**

```
public interface MetingRepository extends MongoRepository<Meting, String> {
    Page<Meting> findAllByRuimteId(String ruimteId, Pageable page);
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service("metingenService")
public class MetingServiceImpl implements MetingService {

  // could I try-catch this?
  @Autowired
  private MetingRepository metingRepository;

    @Override
    public Meting addMeting(Meting meting) {
      // try-catch does not solve the issue here
      return metingRepository.save(meting);
    }
  }
}
```

The only **test** I have, automatically generated:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MetingenServiceApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

}
```

**Stacktrace:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metingResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'metingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metingenService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'metingRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metingRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]

Comment: If you want to optionally autowire this repo you can use @Autowired(required = false)

Comment: @Noixes even with required=false, `mvn package` runs the repository and tries to connect. I'm lost because there is no point I can catch those exceptions for as far as I know

Comment: Why is the mongodb service not reachable?

Comment: when you say "it runs spring once"... you mean you have a unit test that is triggered by the build ? You need to show us this Unit Test, in which (depending on what you're doing in it) you need to mock the external dependencies.

Comment: Please add the failing Unit Test to your question. Also, note that a unit test "should" not have external dependencies (such as a running MongoDB instance).

Comment: @Noixes Because there is no database on the build server, only on production. If the MongoDB server would be down, I also want it to gracefully exit.

Comment: @Randy Did you try to introduce a "BUILD_PROFILE" and a "PRODUCTION_PROFILE"? public class MetingServiceImpl can be the production one and you also create an class of MetingService for the build_profile which does not wire to any repository. Can you tell your maven configuration to use specific profiles for different build scenarios?

Comment: @alexbt I added the test, and you are correct this is a test issue apparently. Mocking my repository does not seem to work though :(

Comment: What's the purpose of `MetingenServiceApplicationTests` ?  In most cases you shouldn't use `SpringBootTests`. Why not simple junit without Spring Context ? `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` or `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: @alexbt Thank you. `MockitoJUnitRunner` is what I use now and it works like a charm :) I created this project using Spring Initializr for a Spring Cloud project, and the test was included by default.

Comment: But then, you could also remove the test ;)

Comment: @alexbt Yes you are right, but I'm going to build this test driven after I've settled the most basic buildserver dependencies, so I figured I'd keep the test alive as reference. Now with Mockito I have a proper example ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test is trying to load the complete Spring Context. Thus, it's trying to load a valid `MongoTemplate` to connect to a MongoDB instance.

In most cases, you shouldn't use `@SpringBootTests` (which is for integration tests), instead you can do a normal JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class) // or @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MetingenServiceApplicationTests {
    ...
}
```